# How to add an Icon to own ctype in Page-Module List-View

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

In TYPO3 7.6, I created a new content-element with a new CType.

I have choosen an icon from the icon-factory (content-quote).

I managed to include this icon into the new-element-wizard

```
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.common.elements.myOwnCtype.iconIdentifier = content-quote
```

I managed to include the icon into the dropdown-field "type" when editing the content-element in

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['CType']['config']['items'][]
```

But there must be third place to define icons for ctypes:

When I open Web->Page I get a preview of all content-elements on this page.

Every content-elements has a grey bar on top with an icon corresponding to it's ctype in left corner. This still shows the standard-icon in my case.

How can I change that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can place this code in your EXT:my_extension/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php to set icons for your own CTypes in the header of the backend preview.

```
$originalTtContent = $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content'];
$overridesForTtContent = [
  'ctrl' => [
    'typeicon_classes' => [
        'your_CType' => 'your_icon',
        'your_CType' => 'your_icon',
        'your_CType' => 'your_icon',
    ]
  ]
];
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content'] = array_merge_recursive($originalTtContent, $overridesForTtContent);
```

Comment: Thx, [@kevin-appelt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8164482)! I'm wondering why this isn't mentioned once in the article ["Create a custom content element type"](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/12.4/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/AddingYourOwnContentElements.html).

Answer (score 0):

Given the default setting is

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['ctrl']['typeicon_column'] => 'CType';
```

Register your Icon in ext_tables.php

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconRegistry::class)->registerIcon(
    'mimetypes-x-content-myctype',
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconProvider\BitmapIconProvider::class,
    ['source' => 'EXT:myextension/Resources/Public/Images/mimetypes-x-content-myctype.png']
);
```

Add your icon to typeicon_classes

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['ctrl']['typeicon_classes']['myctype'] => 'mimetypes-x-content-myctype';
```

Where syntax of 'myctype' must match your own CType, given in

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']...
```